# Wrap gulp-markdown in a div

Tags: angularjs, markdown, gulp

Hi I'm using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-markdown

And I want to wrap the following markdown in a div:

```
<div ng-show="tab.title=='Grades'">
  <!-- markdown goes here -->
</div>
```

Is this possible or is there a better gulp tool to do this?

Markdown:

```
Grades
------

###A-levels (AAA)
 - Applicants must take Chemistry plus one subject from Biology/Human Biology, Maths or Physics
 - General studies not accepted

###GCSEs
 - Applicants must have minimum of a C in English and Maths. A combination of Grade A and B passes are expected especially in science subjects. Biology is recommended; Physics is recommended (or Dual Award Science).

###Scottish Highers (AAA)
 - Applicants must have chemistry to a minimum of a grade B plus two subjects from Biology/Human Biology, Maths & Physics
 - You cannot apply at the start of S5 level. All applications from high school must be made in S6.


###International Baccalaureate (36 points)
 - 36 points are required overall (excluding TOK & bonus points)
 - Applicants must achieve/be predicted 3 subjects at Higher Level at Grade 6 or higher
 - Applicants must take 3 other subjects at Standard Level and achieve an average of Grade 6
 - Applicants must take Chemistry and offer two of Maths, Biology or Physics over Standard and Higher levels
```

Comment: This might work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wrap